# How can I use st.peek() function in java if I pushed a pair of elements?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, push, peek

I created a user defined class pair to add two elements in stack. But how can I use peek function of the stack? I want to access the "element" of pair class using peek.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Example {
    public static class pair{
        int element;
        int idx;
        public pair(int element, int idx){
            this.element = element;
            this.idx = idx;
        }
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<pair> st= new Stack<pair>();
        pair p1 = new pair(100,2);
        st.push(p1);
        System.out.println(st.peek());
    }
}
```

- When I am trying to print st.peek() I got output: Example$pair@4617c264

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `toString()` in your pair class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return element + ", " + idx;
}
```

This is an example.  It is up to you what you want returned in the string.  You could also do something like:

```
return "Element = %d, Idx = %d".formatted(element, idx);
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... But how can I use peek function of the stack? ..."*

The *[Stack#peek](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Stack.html#peek())* method is going to return the object, in this case a *pair*.

> *"... I want to access the "element" of pair class using peek ..."*

You can access the *element* field via *dot-notation*.

```java
st.peek().element
```

> *"... When I am trying to print st.peek() I got output: Example$pair@4617c264"*

This is just a naming scheme used by Java, which will be returned when trying to convert an *Object* to a *String*.

The *[System#out#println](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object))* method is taking an *Object* as a parameter, not a *String*.

Here is the source, for *println*.
*[GitHub – jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#L1186)*.

Which is using the following, more-or-less—where *x* is of type, *Object*.

```java
String s = String.valueOf(x);
```

An *Object* can provide a *String* resolution by overriding the inherited *[Object#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString())* method.

Here is the source, for *Object#toString*.
*[GitHub – jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java#L265)*.

So, if you wanted, you can add a *toString* method, to your *pair* class.

```java
public static class pair{
    int element;
    int idx;
    public pair(int element, int idx){
        this.element = element;
        this.idx = idx;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(element);
    }
}
```

Then, when using the following,

```java
System.out.println(st.peek());
```

You're output will be,

```
100
```